# Date from .xlsx automatically getting converted into 5 digit number

Tags: javascript, mysql, angular, excel

I am trying to take data from xls and upload it to database(sql), in the xls I have a date column in format dd-mm-yyyy, but it is somehow getting converted to 5 digit number and sql is throwing error "Incorrect date value: '43831' for column 'date_of_birth' at row 1".

JS format : date;
SQL format : date;

Comment: You should explain in detail how are you uploading the data taken from xls to sql. Are you doing this with copy and paste? A program outside excel? inside excel? ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel stores it's dates as the number of days since Jan 1 1900,  Javascript uses a system similar to unix time,  1 Jan 1970, but use milliseconds instead of days.

So using this info, a quick conversion should look something like ->

```js
const excelEpoc = new Date(1900, 0, -1).getTime();
const msDay = 86400000;

function excelDateToJavascript(excelDate) {
  return  new Date(excelEpoc + excelDate * msDay);
}

console.log(excelDateToJavascript(43831));
```